# Python Polars join on column with greater or equal

Tags: python, python-polars, rust-polars

I have two polars dataframe, one dataframe `df_1` with two columns `start` and `end` the other dataframe `df_2` one with a column `dates` and I want to do a left join on `df_2` under the condition that the `dates` column is in between the `start` and `end` column.

To make it more obvious what I want to do here is an example

**DATA**

```
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

df_1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["abc", "abc", "456"],
        "start": [date(2022, 1, 1), date(2022, 3, 4), date(2022, 5, 11)],
        "end": [date(2022, 2, 4), date(2022, 3, 10), date(2022, 5, 16)],
        "value": [10, 3, 4]

    }
)

df_2 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["abc", "abc", "456", "abc", "abc", "456"],
        "dates": [date(2022, 1, 2), date(2022, 3, 4), date(2022, 5, 11), date(2022, 1, 4), date(2022, 3, 7), date(2022, 5, 13)],
    }
)
```

So now I would join on `id` and that `dates` is in between `start` and `end` and the result should look like that

**RESULT**

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ dates      ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ date       ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪════════════╪═══════╡
│ abc ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ abc ┆ 2022-03-04 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ abc ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ abc ┆ 2022-03-07 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-13 ┆ 4     │
└─────┴────────────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm going to assume that your intervals in `df_1` do not overlap for a particular id - otherwise, there may not be a unique `value` that we can assign to the id/dates combinations in `df_2`.)

One way to do this is with [`join_asof`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.join_asof.html#polars.DataFrame.join_asof).

##### The Algorithm

```py
(
    df_2
    .sort("dates")
    .join_asof(
        df_1.sort("start"),
        by="id",
        left_on="dates",
        right_on="start",
        strategy="backward",
    )
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col('dates') <= pl.col('end'))
        .then(pl.col('value'))
        .otherwise(None)
    )
    .select(['id', 'dates', 'value'])
)
```

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ dates      ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ date       ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪════════════╪═══════╡
│ abc ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ abc ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ abc ┆ 2022-03-04 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ abc ┆ 2022-03-07 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-13 ┆ 4     │
└─────┴────────────┴───────┘
```

##### In Steps

First, let's append some additional rows to `df_2`, to show what will happen if a particular row is not contained in an interval in `df_1`.  I'll also add a row number, for easier inspection.

```py
df_2 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["abc", "abc", "456", "abc", "abc", "456", "abc", "abc", "abc"],
        "dates": [
            date(2022, 1, 2),
            date(2022, 3, 4),
            date(2022, 5, 11),
            date(2022, 1, 4),
            date(2022, 3, 7),
            date(2022, 5, 13),
            date(2021, 12, 31),
            date(2022, 3, 1),
            date(2023, 1, 1),
        ],
    }
).with_row_count()
df_2
```

```
shape: (9, 3)
┌────────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ id  ┆ dates      │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ u32    ┆ str ┆ date       │
╞════════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-01-02 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-03-04 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-01-04 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-03-07 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 456 ┆ 2022-05-13 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6      ┆ abc ┆ 2021-12-31 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-03-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8      ┆ abc ┆ 2023-01-01 │
└────────┴─────┴────────────┘
```

The `join_asof` step finds the latest `start` date that is on or before the `dates` date.  Since intervals do not overlap, this is the only interval that might contain the `dates` date.

For our purposes, I'll make a copy of the `start` column so that we can inspect the results. (The `start` column will not be in the results of the `join_asof`.)

Note that for a `join_asof`, both DataFrames must be sorted by the `asof` columns (`dates` and `start` in this case).

```py
(
    df_2
    .sort("dates")
    .join_asof(
        df_1.sort("start").with_column(pl.col("start").alias("start_df1")),
        by="id",
        left_on="dates",
        right_on="start",
        strategy="backward",
    )
    .sort("row_nr")
)
```

```
shape: (9, 6)
┌────────┬─────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ id  ┆ dates      ┆ end        ┆ value ┆ start_df1  │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ u32    ┆ str ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64   ┆ date       │
╞════════╪═════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2022-02-04 ┆ 10    ┆ 2022-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-03-04 ┆ 2022-03-10 ┆ 3     ┆ 2022-03-04 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     ┆ 2022-05-11 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 2022-02-04 ┆ 10    ┆ 2022-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-03-07 ┆ 2022-03-10 ┆ 3     ┆ 2022-03-04 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 456 ┆ 2022-05-13 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     ┆ 2022-05-11 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6      ┆ abc ┆ 2021-12-31 ┆ null       ┆ null  ┆ null       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-03-01 ┆ 2022-02-04 ┆ 10    ┆ 2022-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8      ┆ abc ┆ 2023-01-01 ┆ 2022-03-10 ┆ 3     ┆ 2022-03-04 │
└────────┴─────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

The last three rows are the ones that I added.

In the last step, we'll inspect the `end` date, and null out any values where `dates` is beyond `end`.

```py
(
    df_2
    .sort("dates")
    .join_asof(
        df_1.sort("start").with_column(pl.col("start").alias("start_df1")),
        by="id",
        left_on="dates",
        right_on="start",
        strategy="backward",
    )
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col('dates') <= pl.col('end'))
        .then(pl.col('value'))
        .otherwise(None)
    )
    .sort("row_nr")
)
```

```
shape: (9, 6)
┌────────┬─────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ id  ┆ dates      ┆ end        ┆ value ┆ start_df1  │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ u32    ┆ str ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64   ┆ date       │
╞════════╪═════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2022-02-04 ┆ 10    ┆ 2022-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-03-04 ┆ 2022-03-10 ┆ 3     ┆ 2022-03-04 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     ┆ 2022-05-11 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 2022-02-04 ┆ 10    ┆ 2022-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-03-07 ┆ 2022-03-10 ┆ 3     ┆ 2022-03-04 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 456 ┆ 2022-05-13 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     ┆ 2022-05-11 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6      ┆ abc ┆ 2021-12-31 ┆ null       ┆ null  ┆ null       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ abc ┆ 2022-03-01 ┆ 2022-02-04 ┆ null  ┆ 2022-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8      ┆ abc ┆ 2023-01-01 ┆ 2022-03-10 ┆ null  ┆ 2022-03-04 │
└────────┴─────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

You can see that the last three rows that I added (which purposely don't match any intervals in `df_1`) have `null` as `value`.

Instead of using `when/then/otherwise` to set `value` to null, you can  filter these out, if that's what you need.