# python-polars: Group dataframe by values in another Dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

I have 2 dataframes:

df1

```
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────┐
│ start               ┆ end                 ┆ id  │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ --- │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64 │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═════╡
│ 2022-01-10 01:02:03 ┆ 2022-01-10 03:02:03 ┆ 1   │
│ 2022-01-10 05:02:03 ┆ 2022-01-10 07:02:03 ┆ 1   │
│ 2022-01-10 10:02:03 ┆ 2022-01-10 12:02:03 ┆ 2   │
│ 2022-01-10 03:02:03 ┆ 2022-01-10 05:02:03 ┆ 2   │
│ 2022-01-10 07:02:03 ┆ 2022-01-10 09:02:03 ┆ 3   │
│ 2022-01-10 02:02:03 ┆ 2022-01-10 04:02:03 ┆ 4   │
│ 2022-01-10 01:02:03 ┆ 2022-01-10 03:02:03 ┆ 3   │
│ 2022-01-10 02:02:03 ┆ 2022-01-10 04:02:03 ┆ 2   │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────┘
```

df2

```
┌─────┬─────────────────────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ time                ┆ data │
│ --- ┆ ---                 ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪═════════════════════╪══════╡
│ 4   ┆ 2022-01-10 08:53:03 ┆ 21   │
│ 4   ┆ 2022-01-10 06:22:03 ┆ 21   │
│ 1   ┆ 2022-01-10 04:08:03 ┆ 20   │
│ 2   ┆ 2022-01-10 09:20:03 ┆ 29   │
│ ... ┆ ...                 ┆ ...  │
│ 3   ┆ 2022-01-10 03:59:03 ┆ 30   │
│ 1   ┆ 2022-01-10 07:44:03 ┆ 24   │
│ 1   ┆ 2022-01-10 06:40:03 ┆ 28   │
│ 2   ┆ 2022-01-10 04:13:03 ┆ 24   │
└─────┴─────────────────────┴──────┘
```

I want to split `df2` into multiple dataframes, based on the `start`, `end`, and `id` columns from `df1`.

I am currently doing this like this, but I want to avoid using a `for` loop. Are there any more efficient ways of doing this? Perhaps with `df.groupby`?

My current solution:

```
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

### Just some example data ####

records1 = []
dates = [1, 5, 10, 3, 7, 2, 1, 2]
idd   = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]

for i in range(len(dates)):
    start = datetime(2022, 1, 10, dates[i], 2, 3)
    end = datetime(2022, 1, 10, dates[i]+2, 2, 3)
    records1.append({'start':start, 'end':end, 'id':idd[i]})

df1 = pl.from_records(records1)

records2 = []
hours = [8, 6, 4, 9, 4, 0, 6, 2, 7, 0, 0, 3, 7, 6, 4]
minutes  = [53, 22, 8, 20, 53, 30, 58, 15, 49, 36, 30, 59, 44, 40, 13]
idd   = [4, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2]
data = [21, 21, 20, 29, 22, 25, 20, 26, 23, 21, 30, 30, 24, 28, 24]

for i in range(len(data)):
    time = datetime(2022, 1, 10, hours[i], minutes[i], 3)
    records2.append({'id': idd[i], 'time':time, 'data':data[i]})

df2 = pl.from_records(records2)

################### Start of code ##################

for i in range(len(df1)):
    df3 = df2.filter(
        (pl.col('time').is_between(df1['start'][i],  df1['end'][i])) & 
        (pl.col('id') == df1['id'][i]))
   
    print(df3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing the equivalent of a `.join().filter()`

```
(df2.join(df1, on="id")
    .filter(pl.col("time").is_between(pl.col("start"), pl.col("end"))))
```

```
shape: (4, 5)
┌─────┬─────────────────────┬──────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ id  | time                | data | start               | end                 │
│ --- | ---                 | ---  | ---                 | ---                 │
│ i64 | datetime[μs]        | i64  | datetime[μs]        | datetime[μs]        │
╞═════╪═════════════════════╪══════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 1   | 2022-01-10 06:58:03 | 20   | 2022-01-10 05:02:03 | 2022-01-10 07:02:03 │
├─────┼─────────────────────┼──────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ 3   | 2022-01-10 02:15:03 | 26   | 2022-01-10 01:02:03 | 2022-01-10 03:02:03 │
├─────┼─────────────────────┼──────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ 1   | 2022-01-10 06:40:03 | 28   | 2022-01-10 05:02:03 | 2022-01-10 07:02:03 │
├─────┼─────────────────────┼──────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ 2   | 2022-01-10 04:13:03 | 24   | 2022-01-10 03:02:03 | 2022-01-10 05:02:03 │
└─────┴─────────────────────┴──────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

You can then `.groupby(["id", "start", "end"])` to process each interval/range.

Depending if there are overlapping intervals or not you could also use `.join_asof()` as explained in [Python Polars join on column with greater or equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73176563/python-polars-join-on-column-with-greater-or-equal) which is more efficient.

```
(df2.sort("time")
    .join_asof(
        df1.sort("start").with_column(pl.col("start").alias("time")), 
        on="time", 
        by="id")
    .filter(pl.col("time").is_between(pl.col("start"), pl.col("end"))))
```

```
shape: (4, 5)
┌─────┬─────────────────────┬──────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ id  | time                | data | start               | end                 │
│ --- | ---                 | ---  | ---                 | ---                 │
│ i64 | datetime[μs]        | i64  | datetime[μs]        | datetime[μs]        │
╞═════╪═════════════════════╪══════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 3   | 2022-01-10 02:15:03 | 26   | 2022-01-10 01:02:03 | 2022-01-10 03:02:03 │
├─────┼─────────────────────┼──────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ 2   | 2022-01-10 04:13:03 | 24   | 2022-01-10 03:02:03 | 2022-01-10 05:02:03 │
├─────┼─────────────────────┼──────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ 1   | 2022-01-10 06:40:03 | 28   | 2022-01-10 05:02:03 | 2022-01-10 07:02:03 │
├─────┼─────────────────────┼──────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ 1   | 2022-01-10 06:58:03 | 20   | 2022-01-10 05:02:03 | 2022-01-10 07:02:03 │
└─────┴─────────────────────┴──────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an as_of join to find the values where `start` is closest to `time` (without going over) and then filter out any rows where `time` is bigger than `end`.  Doing an as_of join requires the dfs be sorted first so it'll look like this:

```
(df2.sort('time')
 .join_asof(df1.sort('start'), 
            left_on='time', right_on='start', by='id', strategy='backward')
 .filter(pl.col('time')<=pl.col('end')))
```

The `left_on` and `right_on` match the not-equal columns where a match comes from being closest (in just one direction) while the `by` parameter is to specify exact match columns, in this case `id`.  The `strategy` specifies that the values of the left column should go in that direction (backwards) until it finds a match.

You could also do it in the opposite direction if you want:

```
(df2.sort('time')
 .join_asof(df1.sort('end'), 
            left_on='time', right_on='end', by='id', strategy='forward')
 .filter(pl.col('time')>=pl.col('start')))
```

Either way you get:

```
shape: (4, 5)
┌─────┬─────────────────────┬──────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ time                ┆ data ┆ start               ┆ end                 │
│ --- ┆ ---                 ┆ ---  ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 │
│ i64 ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64  ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════╪═════════════════════╪══════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 3   ┆ 2022-01-10 02:15:03 ┆ 26   ┆ 2022-01-10 01:02:03 ┆ 2022-01-10 03:02:03 │
│ 2   ┆ 2022-01-10 04:13:03 ┆ 24   ┆ 2022-01-10 03:02:03 ┆ 2022-01-10 05:02:03 │
│ 1   ┆ 2022-01-10 06:40:03 ┆ 28   ┆ 2022-01-10 05:02:03 ┆ 2022-01-10 07:02:03 │
│ 1   ┆ 2022-01-10 06:58:03 ┆ 20   ┆ 2022-01-10 05:02:03 ┆ 2022-01-10 07:02:03 │
└─────┴─────────────────────┴──────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Another thing to remember is that it is a left-join so whichever df you want the rows from is the one from which you call the method.  In other words, you can't do a version of `df1.join_asof(df2,...)` to get your desired result in this case.