# Polars column from conditioned look up of dictionary values

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, iteration, python-polars

I want to map a key in one Polars DataFrame to another Polars DF base on the relationships between columns. This is just a sample, the full DF1 and DF2 is much larger (2.5 million and 1.5 million rows respectively.

```py
DF1 = = pl.DataFrame({
'chr' : ["GL000008.2", "GL000008.2", "GL000008.2", "GL000008.2","GL000008.2", "GL000008.2"], 
'start': [14516,17380,17381,20177,22254,24357], 
'end': [14534,17399,17399,20195,22274,24377]
})

DF2 = = pl.DataFrame({ 
'key' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
'chrom' : ["GL000008.2", "GL000008.2", "GL000008.2", "GL000008.2","GL000008.2", "GL000008.2"], 
'start': [14516,15377,17376,20177,22254, 24357], 
'end': [14534,15403,17399,20195,22274,24377]})
```

What I want is:

```py
DF1 = = pl.DataFrame({
'chr' : ["GL000008.2", "GL000008.2", "GL000008.2", "GL000008.2","GL000008.2", "GL000008.2"], 
'start': [14516,17380,17381,20177,22254,24357], 
'end': [14534,17399,17399,20195,22274,24377],
'key': [1,3,3,4,5,6]
})
```

I'd like to assign the `key` from *DF2* to *DF1* when `chrom` matches `chr` and the `start` and `end` in *DF1* are contained within the `begin` and `end` in *DF2*.

I first attempted to iterate through the rows of *DF1*, looking up the matching entry in *DF2*:

```py
sz = len(DF1[:,0])

for i in range(sz):
    DF1[i,"key"] = DF2.filter(
        (pl.col("chrom") == DF1[i,"chr"])\
        & (pl.col("begin") <= DF1[i,"start"])\
        & (pl.col("end") >= DF1[i,"end"])
        ).select('key')[0,0]
```

Row iteration through a DF is incredibly slow. This takes about 10 hours.

I also tried using a np.array instead of directly into the df. thats a little faster, but still very slow.

I'm looking for a way to accomplish this using the native Polar's data structure. I don't have key to join on so the `join` and `join_asof` strategies don't seem to work.

Comment: can you make your example reproducible and show expected output please?

Comment: Would this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73177515/20557510

Comment: Another example would be: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5004#issuecomment-1259784083

Comment: @ignoring_gravity I tried to add a better explanation, sorry.

Comment: @ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ, Thanks for your suggestions - but I don't have a key to join on - its really just three conditions. In fact, the key is what I'm trying to establish in DF1 so I can do joins.

Comment: thanks @JimBeck - it's still not reproducible though. can you post something we can copy and paste?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity  I added the actual full DF1 and DF2 via a link to a repo - so they can be downloaded. The code above can be run on those files. I'm not sure what else I can provide to make it copy and paste.

Comment: something like `df1 = pl.DataFrame({'start': [14516, 14517, ...], 'end': [14712, ...]})`, `df2 = ...` . We should be able to run your code without downloading data

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Thanks for the guidance. And just to be clear - the code I wrote works - its just so bloody slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

join and filter should give you what you need:

```py
(
    df1.join(df2, left_on="chr", right_on="chrom")
    .filter(
        (pl.col("start") >= pl.col("start_right"))
        & (pl.col("end") <= pl.col("end_right"))
    )
    .drop(["start_right", "end_right"])
)
```

```py
shape: (6, 4)
┌────────────┬───────┬───────┬─────┐
│ chr        ┆ start ┆ end   ┆ key │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str        ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64 │
╞════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ GL000008.2 ┆ 14516 ┆ 14534 ┆ 1   │
│ GL000008.2 ┆ 17380 ┆ 17399 ┆ 3   │
│ GL000008.2 ┆ 17381 ┆ 17399 ┆ 3   │
│ GL000008.2 ┆ 20177 ┆ 20195 ┆ 4   │
│ GL000008.2 ┆ 22254 ┆ 22274 ┆ 5   │
│ GL000008.2 ┆ 24357 ┆ 24377 ┆ 6   │
└────────────┴───────┴───────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I was thinking I couldn't use a join because the `chr` field is a many to many relationship between both DF1 and DF2.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `join_asof` might provide a performant solution:

```py
(
    DF1
    .sort('start')
    .join_asof(
        DF2.sort('start'),
        by_left="chr",
        by_right="chrom",
        on="start",
        strategy="backward")
    .filter(
        pl.col('end') <= pl.col('end_right')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (6, 5)
┌────────────┬───────┬───────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ chr        ┆ start ┆ end   ┆ key ┆ end_right │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ str        ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64 ┆ i64       │
╞════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ GL000008.2 ┆ 14516 ┆ 14534 ┆ 1   ┆ 14534     │
│ GL000008.2 ┆ 17380 ┆ 17399 ┆ 3   ┆ 17399     │
│ GL000008.2 ┆ 17381 ┆ 17399 ┆ 3   ┆ 17399     │
│ GL000008.2 ┆ 20177 ┆ 20195 ┆ 4   ┆ 20195     │
│ GL000008.2 ┆ 22254 ┆ 22274 ┆ 5   ┆ 22274     │
│ GL000008.2 ┆ 24357 ┆ 24377 ┆ 6   ┆ 24377     │
└────────────┴───────┴───────┴─────┴───────────┘
```

Note: this assumes that your start-end intervals in DF2 do not overlap.