# Python Polars: Conditional Join by Date Range

Tags: python, join, python-polars

First of all, there seem to be some similar questions answered already. However, I couldn't find this specific case, where the conditional columns are also part of the join columns:

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pl.DataFrame({"timestamp": ['2023-01-01 00:00:00', '2023-05-01 00:00:00', '2023-10-01 00:00:00'], "value": [2, 5, 9]})

df1 = df1.with_columns(
    pl.col("timestamp").str.to_datetime().alias("timestamp"),
)

┌─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ timestamp           ┆ value │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2     │
│ 2023-05-01 00:00:00 ┆ 5     │
│ 2023-10-01 00:00:00 ┆ 9     │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘

df2 = pl.DataFrame({"date_start": ['2022-12-31 00:00:00', '2023-01-02 00:00:00'], "date_end": ['2023-04-30 00:00:00', '2023-05-05 00:00:00'], "label": [0, 1]})

df2 = df2.with_columns(
    pl.col("date_start").str.to_datetime().alias("date_start"),
    pl.col("date_end").str.to_datetime().alias("date_end"),
)

┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ date_start          ┆ date_end            ┆ label │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2022-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-04-30 00:00:00 ┆ 0     │
│ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-05-05 00:00:00 ┆ 1     │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┘
```

I want to join `label` of the second `polars.Dataframe` (df2) onto the first `polars.Dataframe` (df1) - but only when the column value of `timestamp` (`polars.Datetime`) is within the date ranges given in `date_start` and `date_end`, respectively. 
Since I basically want a `left join` on df1, the column `label` should be `None` when the column value of `timestamp` isn't at all covered by df2.

The tricky part for me is, that there isn't an actual `on` for df2 since its a range of dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pure polars Solution

Assuming that your `timestamp` is at the day level you can use `pl.date_range` in a `group_by` to generate every day between each `start_date` and `end_date`, then explode those out to `join` on.

```py
df_agg = (
    df2.group_by("label")
    .agg(
        pl.date_range(pl.col("date_start"), pl.col("date_end"), "1d").alias("timestamp")
    )
    .explode("timestamp")
)

df_agg = df1.join(df_agg, how="left", on=["timestamp"])

df_agg
```

Result:

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ timestamp           ┆ value ┆ label │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2     ┆ 0     │
│ 2023-03-01 00:00:00 ┆ 4     ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-03-01 00:00:00 ┆ 4     ┆ 0     │
│ 2023-05-01 00:00:00 ┆ 5     ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-10-01 00:00:00 ┆ 9     ┆ null  │
└─────────────────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

### Using duckdb

Seeing as you noted `sqlite` to your answer, using `duckdb` might a better solution if you need timestamps at a finer grain. This can pretty transparently convert polars' DataFrames in and out.

```py
import duckdb

ddb = duckdb.connect()
ddf_df = ddb.query(
    "select * from df1 left join df2 on df1.timestamp between df2.date_start and df2.date_end"
).pl()

ddf_df
```

Results:

```
shape: (5, 5)
┌─────────────────────┬───────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ timestamp           ┆ value ┆ date_start          ┆ date_end            ┆ label │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2     ┆ 2022-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-04-30 00:00:00 ┆ 0     │
│ 2023-03-01 00:00:00 ┆ 4     ┆ 2022-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-04-30 00:00:00 ┆ 0     │
│ 2023-03-01 00:00:00 ┆ 4     ┆ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-05-05 00:00:00 ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-05-01 00:00:00 ┆ 5     ┆ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-05-05 00:00:00 ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-10-01 00:00:00 ┆ 9     ┆ null                ┆ null                ┆ null  │
└─────────────────────┴───────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Same problem with the overlapping date ranges (produces duplicate), but I think I can adapt your solution with duckdb from here on - even though its not exactly a polars solution but concise, fast, readable and integrable. Thank you very much!

Comment: @OliverHennhoefer - I'm glad this might work for you. As your example contained overlapping spans, it would have been helpful to specify how you wanted to handle the duplicated spans (e.g. take the first effective span, take the latest effective span, duplicate the rows). The `between` operator, as my answer shows, produces a row for every matching span.

Comment: True, didn't think of it at the time of writing.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1

So if there is a one to one relationship between timestamp and date_range (so there exists only one date_range in which a timestamp can be) then you can work with this solution ([see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73177515/10120952))

```
df1 = df1.sort("timestamp")
df2 = df2.sort("date_start")

df_merged = df1.join_asof(
    df2, left_on="timestamp", right_on="date_start", strategy="backward"
)
df_merged = df_merged.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("timestamp") <= pl.col("date_end"))
    .then(pl.col("label"))
    .otherwise(None)
).select(["timestamp", "value", "label"])

df_merged



shape: (3, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ timestamp           ┆ value ┆ label │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2     ┆ 0     │
│ 2023-05-01 00:00:00 ┆ 5     ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-10-01 00:00:00 ┆ 9     ┆ null  │
└─────────────────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

## Solution 2

If this kind of relationship doesn't exists you can do a cross join and then filter but that could become very expensive very quickly.
I adapted your example from before so this case would be covered.

```
df1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": [
            "2023-01-01 00:00:00",
            "2023-02-01 00:00:00",
            "2023-05-01 00:00:00",
            "2023-10-01 00:00:00",
        ],
        "value": [2, 8, 5, 9],
    }
)

df1 = df1.with_columns(
    pl.col("timestamp").str.to_datetime().alias("timestamp"),
)

df2 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "date_start": ["2022-12-31 00:00:00", "2023-01-02 00:00:00"],
        "date_end": ["2023-04-30 00:00:00", "2023-05-05 00:00:00"],
        "label": [0, 1],
    }
)

df2 = df2.with_columns(
    pl.col("date_start").str.to_datetime().alias("date_start"),
    pl.col("date_end").str.to_datetime().alias("date_end"),
)


df_merged = df1.with_columns(pl.lit(1).alias("join_col")).join(
    df2.with_columns(pl.lit(1).alias("join_col")), on="join_col", how="outer"
)
df_merged = (
    df_merged.with_columns(
        pl.when(
            (pl.col("timestamp") <= pl.col("date_end"))
            & (pl.col("timestamp") >= pl.col("date_start"))
        )
        .then(pl.col("label"))
        .otherwise(None)
    )
    .filter(pl.col("label").is_not_null())
    .select(["timestamp", "value", "label"])
)

df_merged = df1.join(df_merged, on=["timestamp", "value"], how="left")

df_merged

┌─────────────────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ timestamp           ┆ value ┆ label │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2     ┆ 0     │
│ 2023-02-01 00:00:00 ┆ 8     ┆ 0     │
│ 2023-02-01 00:00:00 ┆ 8     ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-05-01 00:00:00 ┆ 5     ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-10-01 00:00:00 ┆ 9     ┆ null  │
└─────────────────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer! Unfortunately, my date ranges not only overlap (my answer actually has the same 'problem' with this circumstance) but are also relatively large in regard to cross-joining.

Answer (score 0):

I want to provide the respective solution for `pandas` that I just found, just in case there won't be an actual answer using `polars`. Furthermore, I think the whole task might be impossible to accomplish with `polars` in its current `version 0.19` since the pandas solution currently does not work within `polars` yet (see last part of my answer):

Solution with `pandas` and `sqlite` as provided in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627968/merge-pandas-dataframes-where-one-value-is-between-two-others):

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

df1 = pl.DataFrame({"timestamp": ['2023-01-01 00:00:00', '2023-05-01 00:00:00', '2023-10-01 00:00:00'], "value": [2, 5, 9]})
df1 = df1.with_columns(
    pl.col("timestamp").str.to_datetime().alias("timestamp"),
)

df2 = pl.DataFrame({"date_start": ['2022-12-31 00:00:00', '2023-01-02 00:00:00'], "date_end": ['2023-04-30 00:00:00', '2023-05-05 00:00:00'], "label": [0, 1]})
df2 = df2.with_columns(
    pl.col("date_start").str.to_datetime().alias("date_start"),
    pl.col("date_end").str.to_datetime().alias("date_end"),
)

df1.to_pandas().to_sql('df1', conn, index=False)
df2.to_pandas().to_sql('df2', conn, index=False)

qry = '''
    select * from df1 left join df2 on df1.timestamp between df2.date_start and df2.date_end
    '''
df = pl.from_pandas(pd.read_sql_query(qry, conn))
```

Respective solution in `polars` that doesn't implement the `sql` operator `between` yet (adapted from this [source](https://stuffbyyuki.com/how-to-use-sql-in-polars/?utm_content=cmp-true)):

```
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.DataFrame({"timestamp": ['2023-01-01 00:00:00', '2023-05-01 00:00:00', '2023-10-01 00:00:00'], "value": [2, 5, 9]})
df1 = df1.with_columns(
    pl.col("timestamp").str.to_datetime().alias("timestamp"),
)

df2 = pl.DataFrame({"date_start": ['2022-12-31 00:00:00', '2023-01-02 00:00:00'], "date_end": ['2023-04-30 00:00:00', '2023-05-05 00:00:00'], "label": [0, 1]})
df2 = df2.with_columns(
    pl.col("date_start").str.to_datetime().alias("date_start"),
    pl.col("date_end").str.to_datetime().alias("date_end"),
)

sql = pl.SQLContext()
sql.register('df1', df1)
sql.register('df2', df2)

result_df = sql.execute(
    """
      select * from df1 left join df2 on df1.timestamp between df2.date_start and df2.date_end
    """
).collect()

print(result_df)
```

Respective `error` message:

```
InvalidOperationError: SQL join constraint On(Between { expr: CompoundIdentifier([Ident { value: "df1", quote_style: None }, Ident { value: "timestamp", quote_style: None }]), negated: false, low: CompoundIdentifier([Ident { value: "df2", quote_style: None }, Ident { value: "date_start", quote_style: None }]), high: CompoundIdentifier([Ident { value: "df2", quote_style: None }, Ident { value: "date_end", quote_style: None }]) }) is not yet supported
```