# How to label a pl.Series using two pl.DataFrame not joined with null values?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, python-polars

## The problem

I have pl.DataFrame df_signals

```
┌──────────────┬──────┬─────────────────────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ series_id    ┆ step ┆ timestamp               ┆ sig1     ┆ sig2     │
│ ---          ┆ ---  ┆ ---                     ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str          ┆ u32  ┆ datetime[μs, UTC]       ┆ f32      ┆ f32      │
╞══════════════╪══════╪═════════════════════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 038441c925bb ┆ 0    ┆ 2018-08-14 19:30:00 UTC ┆ 0.550596 ┆ 0.017739 │
│ f8a8de8bdd00 ┆ 0    ┆ 2018-08-14 19:30:00 UTC ┆ 0.220596 ┆ 0.077739 │
│ …            ┆ …    ┆ …                       ┆ …        ┆ …        │
└──────────────┴──────┴─────────────────────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

and another pl.DataFrame df_events

```
┌──────────────┬───────┬────────┬───────┬─────────────────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┐
│ series_id    ┆ night ┆ event  ┆ step  ┆ timestamp               ┆ onset_step ┆ wakeup_step │
│ ---          ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---                     ┆ ---        ┆ ---         │
│ str          ┆ i64   ┆ str    ┆ u32   ┆ datetime[μs, UTC]       ┆ u32        ┆ u32         │
╞══════════════╪═══════╪════════╪═══════╪═════════════════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 038441c925bb ┆ 1     ┆ onset  ┆ 4879  ┆ 2018-08-15 02:26:00 UTC ┆ 4879       ┆ null        │
│ 038441c925bb ┆ 1     ┆ wakeup ┆ 10932 ┆ 2018-08-15 10:41:00 UTC ┆ null       ┆ 10932       │
│ …            ┆ …     ┆ …      ┆ …     ┆ …                       ┆ …          ┆ …           │
└──────────────┴───────┴────────┴───────┴─────────────────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┘
```

I want to set a new column 'state' which should be :

- 0 if the series_id is awake
- 1 if the series_id is sleeping

It looks easy but I wasn't able to compute it efficiently.

How can I solve this, minimizing the computation as I have a lot of data ?

---

## Reproducing

I made artificial data :

3 series ['A','B','C']

- A sleep from

```
2022-01-01 02:00:00 -> 2022-01-01 14:00:00 | [3-15[
2022-01-01 22:00:00 -> 2022-01-02 08:00:00 | [23-33[
```

- B sleep from

```
2022-01-01 03:00:00 -> 2022-01-01 15:00:00 [4-16[
```

- C
  start sleeping at (but never wake up... => mismatch)

```
2022-01-01 04:00:00 [5-?[
```

```py
timestamps = ([f"2022-01-01 {hour:02d}:00:00" for hour in range(24)] + 
             ["2022-01-02 00:00:00"] +
             [f"2022-01-02 {hour:02d}:00:00" for hour in range(1, 13)])

df_signals = pl.DataFrame({
    "series_id": ["A"] * 37 + ["B"] * 37 + ["C"] * 37,
    "timestamp": timestamps * 3,
    "step": list(range(1, 38)) * 3
})

# Extended events data
df_events = pl.DataFrame({
    "series_id": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"],
    "night": [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    "event": ["onset", "wakeup", "onset", "wakeup", "onset", "wakeup", "onset"],
    "timestamp": ["2022-01-01 02:00:00", "2022-01-01 14:00:00","2022-01-01 22:00:00", "2022-01-02 08:00:00", "2022-01-01 03:00:00",
                 "2022-01-01 15:00:00", "2022-01-01 04:00:00"],
    "step": [3, 15, 23, 33, 4, 16, 5]
})
```

This is what I tried:

```py
df_events = df_events.with_columns(
    onset_step = pl.when(pl.col('event') == 'onset').then(pl.col('step')),
    wakeup_step = pl.when(pl.col('event') == 'wakeup').then(pl.col('step'))
)
df = df_signals.join(df_events, on=['series_id', 'timestamp', 'step'], how='left')
df = df.sort(['series_id', 'step'])
df = df.with_columns(
    onset_step = pl.col('onset_step').forward_fill(),
    wakeup_step = pl.col('wakeup_step').forward_fill()
)
df.with_columns(
    state = (pl.col('step') >= pl.col('onset_step')) & (pl.col('step') <= pl.col('wakeup_step')).fill_null(False)
)
```

However, I'm not sure how to treat the edge case...
When I use forward_fill() it breaks at the start and when I use backward_fill() it breaks at the end...

## Expected Result

```
series_id,timestamp,step,state,event
A,2022-01-01T00:00:00.000000,1,0,
A,2022-01-01T01:00:00.000000,2,0,
A,2022-01-01T02:00:00.000000,3,1,onset
A,2022-01-01T03:00:00.000000,4,1,
A,2022-01-01T04:00:00.000000,5,1,
A,2022-01-01T05:00:00.000000,6,1,
A,2022-01-01T06:00:00.000000,7,1,
A,2022-01-01T07:00:00.000000,8,1,
A,2022-01-01T08:00:00.000000,9,1,
A,2022-01-01T09:00:00.000000,10,1,
A,2022-01-01T10:00:00.000000,11,1,
A,2022-01-01T11:00:00.000000,12,1,
A,2022-01-01T12:00:00.000000,13,1,
A,2022-01-01T13:00:00.000000,14,1,
A,2022-01-01T14:00:00.000000,15,0,wakeup
A,2022-01-01T15:00:00.000000,16,0,
A,2022-01-01T16:00:00.000000,17,0,
A,2022-01-01T17:00:00.000000,18,0,
A,2022-01-01T18:00:00.000000,19,0,
A,2022-01-01T19:00:00.000000,20,0,
A,2022-01-01T20:00:00.000000,21,0,
A,2022-01-01T21:00:00.000000,22,0,
A,2022-01-01T22:00:00.000000,23,1,onset
A,2022-01-01T23:00:00.000000,24,1,
A,2022-01-02T00:00:00.000000,25,1,
A,2022-01-02T01:00:00.000000,26,1,
A,2022-01-02T02:00:00.000000,27,1,
A,2022-01-02T03:00:00.000000,28,1,
A,2022-01-02T04:00:00.000000,29,1,
A,2022-01-02T05:00:00.000000,30,1,
A,2022-01-02T06:00:00.000000,31,1,
A,2022-01-02T07:00:00.000000,32,1,
A,2022-01-02T08:00:00.000000,33,0,wakeup
A,2022-01-02T09:00:00.000000,34,0,
A,2022-01-02T10:00:00.000000,35,0,
A,2022-01-02T11:00:00.000000,36,0,
A,2022-01-02T12:00:00.000000,37,0,
B,2022-01-01T00:00:00.000000,1,0,
B,2022-01-01T01:00:00.000000,2,0,
B,2022-01-01T02:00:00.000000,3,0,
B,2022-01-01T03:00:00.000000,4,1,onset
B,2022-01-01T04:00:00.000000,5,1,
B,2022-01-01T05:00:00.000000,6,1,
B,2022-01-01T06:00:00.000000,7,1,
B,2022-01-01T07:00:00.000000,8,1,
B,2022-01-01T08:00:00.000000,9,1,
B,2022-01-01T09:00:00.000000,10,1,
B,2022-01-01T10:00:00.000000,11,1,
B,2022-01-01T11:00:00.000000,12,1,
B,2022-01-01T12:00:00.000000,13,1,
B,2022-01-01T13:00:00.000000,14,1,
B,2022-01-01T14:00:00.000000,15,1,
B,2022-01-01T15:00:00.000000,16,0,wakeup
B,2022-01-01T16:00:00.000000,17,0,
B,2022-01-01T17:00:00.000000,18,0,
B,2022-01-01T18:00:00.000000,19,0,
B,2022-01-01T19:00:00.000000,20,0,
B,2022-01-01T20:00:00.000000,21,0,
B,2022-01-01T21:00:00.000000,22,0,
B,2022-01-01T22:00:00.000000,23,0,
B,2022-01-01T23:00:00.000000,24,0,
B,2022-01-02T00:00:00.000000,25,0,
B,2022-01-02T01:00:00.000000,26,0,
B,2022-01-02T02:00:00.000000,27,0,
B,2022-01-02T03:00:00.000000,28,0,
B,2022-01-02T04:00:00.000000,29,0,
B,2022-01-02T05:00:00.000000,30,0,
B,2022-01-02T06:00:00.000000,31,0,
B,2022-01-02T07:00:00.000000,32,0,
B,2022-01-02T08:00:00.000000,33,0,
B,2022-01-02T09:00:00.000000,34,0,
B,2022-01-02T10:00:00.000000,35,0,
B,2022-01-02T11:00:00.000000,36,0,
B,2022-01-02T12:00:00.000000,37,0,
C,2022-01-01T00:00:00.000000,1,0,
C,2022-01-01T01:00:00.000000,2,0,
C,2022-01-01T02:00:00.000000,3,0,
C,2022-01-01T03:00:00.000000,4,0,
C,2022-01-01T04:00:00.000000,5,0,onset
C,2022-01-01T05:00:00.000000,6,0,
C,2022-01-01T06:00:00.000000,7,0,
C,2022-01-01T07:00:00.000000,8,0,
C,2022-01-01T08:00:00.000000,9,0,
C,2022-01-01T09:00:00.000000,10,0,
C,2022-01-01T10:00:00.000000,11,0,
C,2022-01-01T11:00:00.000000,12,0,
C,2022-01-01T12:00:00.000000,13,0,
C,2022-01-01T13:00:00.000000,14,0,
C,2022-01-01T14:00:00.000000,15,0,
C,2022-01-01T15:00:00.000000,16,0,
C,2022-01-01T16:00:00.000000,17,0,
C,2022-01-01T17:00:00.000000,18,0,
C,2022-01-01T18:00:00.000000,19,0,
C,2022-01-01T19:00:00.000000,20,0,
C,2022-01-01T20:00:00.000000,21,0,
C,2022-01-01T21:00:00.000000,22,0,
C,2022-01-01T22:00:00.000000,23,0,
C,2022-01-01T23:00:00.000000,24,0,
C,2022-01-02T00:00:00.000000,25,0,
C,2022-01-02T01:00:00.000000,26,0,
C,2022-01-02T02:00:00.000000,27,0,
C,2022-01-02T03:00:00.000000,28,0,
C,2022-01-02T04:00:00.000000,29,0,
C,2022-01-02T05:00:00.000000,30,0,
C,2022-01-02T06:00:00.000000,31,0,
C,2022-01-02T07:00:00.000000,32,0,
C,2022-01-02T08:00:00.000000,33,0,
C,2022-01-02T09:00:00.000000,34,0,
C,2022-01-02T10:00:00.000000,35,0,
C,2022-01-02T11:00:00.000000,36,0,
C,2022-01-02T12:00:00.000000,37,0,
```

Comment: It looks like it could be a `.join_asof` type problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73176563/ - If you could give a runnable code example like in that question and also show the actual final result - it would be easier to help.

Comment: It would be helpful to have the expected result (hard-coded) in the MRE.

Comment: Thanks for the update. `A` sleeps `2022-01-01 02:00:00 -> 2022-01-01 14:00:00` but the output `state` column is `1` (awake?) - Am I misunderstanding the description? The output `A` intervals are `[[3, 15], [16, 22], [23, 33]]` e.g. `offset -> wakeup` is "closed" and `wakeup -> offset` is "open". Are the events guaranteed to be ordered/paired? i.e. if a `wakeup` exists, it will always come directly after a previous `onset` event? Are the `steps` always sequential with no gaps?

Comment: Hello,

I updated the Expected result to be more specific. I inverted wake up and sleep and fixed it accordingly. Some mismatch can exists... Only onset or Only wakeup ... The easier would be to prune them before the treatment probably. The data is consistent for the rest. The steps are consistants with no gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible to combine both datasets and `.sort()` with `nulls_last=True`

```py
df = (
   pl.concat(
       [
          df_signals,
          df_events
       ], 
       how = "diagonal"
   )
   .sort("series_id", "timestamp", "night", nulls_last=True)
)
```

```py
pl.Config(tbl_rows = 16)
```

```py
df.head(16)
```

```py
shape: (16, 5)
┌───────────┬─────────────────────┬──────┬───────┬────────┐
│ series_id ┆ timestamp           ┆ step ┆ night ┆ event  │
│ ---       ┆ ---                 ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ str       ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64  ┆ i64   ┆ str    │
╞═══════════╪═════════════════════╪══════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ null  ┆ null   │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ 2    ┆ null  ┆ null   │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 02:00:00 ┆ 3    ┆ 1     ┆ onset  │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 02:00:00 ┆ 3    ┆ null  ┆ null   │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 03:00:00 ┆ 4    ┆ null  ┆ null   │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 04:00:00 ┆ 5    ┆ null  ┆ null   │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 05:00:00 ┆ 6    ┆ null  ┆ null   │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 7    ┆ null  ┆ null   │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 07:00:00 ┆ 8    ┆ null  ┆ null   │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 08:00:00 ┆ 9    ┆ null  ┆ null   │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 09:00:00 ┆ 10   ┆ null  ┆ null   │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 10:00:00 ┆ 11   ┆ null  ┆ null   │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 11:00:00 ┆ 12   ┆ null  ┆ null   │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ 13   ┆ null  ┆ null   │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 13:00:00 ┆ 14   ┆ null  ┆ null   │
│ A         ┆ 2022-01-01 14:00:00 ┆ 15   ┆ 1     ┆ wakeup │
└───────────┴─────────────────────┴──────┴───────┴────────┘
```

We can `.backward_fill()` the `event` and then remove the `night = 1` rows.

```py
df = (
   df.with_columns(
      pl.col("event").forward_fill(limit=1), # take event from `night = 1` rows
      pl.col("event").backward_fill().over("series_id")
        .map_dict({"onset": 0, "wakeup": 1})
        .fill_null(0)
        .alias("state")
     )
     .filter(night = None)
)
```

```py
df.select(expected.columns).frame_equal(expected)
# True
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working on my dataset your solution runs in 27.4 s

and the other solution with join_asof takes 5 s

Comment: @OlivierD'Ancona Thanks for the update. Yes, but both solutions produce different results. The reason I posted this approach was because it generates the expected output. You would need to add in the extra steps before comparing their runtime.

Comment: Indeed, I was able to use the previous method with prior filtering of mismatching events

Comment: It's still possible the `.json_asof` starting point leads to a faster approach overall - I did not explore that approach any further. I just noticed that when I had all of the data combined this way, that it wasn't much more work to get the final output using the fills.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the type of problem that [`join_asof`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join_asof.html#polars.DataFrame.join_asof) is meant to handle.

You just need to convert your `timestamp` column to a `Datetime` and it appears that step shouldn't be used to join judging from the forward and backward fills you're attempting.

```
df_signals=df_signals.with_columns(
    timestamp=pl.col('timestamp').str.strptime(pl.Datetime,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    )
df_events=df_events.with_columns(
    timestamp=pl.col('timestamp').str.strptime(pl.Datetime,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    )

(
    df_signals
    .join_asof(
        df_events.drop('step'), on='timestamp', by='series_id'
        )
    .with_columns(
        state=(pl.col('event')=='wakeup').cast(pl.Int32)
        )
)
```

This assumes that 'wakeup` means awake and anything else means asleep. You'll have to tweak that bool expression to satisfy extra cases. It also assumes no default, that is to say if there are times in signals before events they'll be null. Changing the default would just be a matter of tweaking the bool expression as well.